# ASP.NET - URL redirection after authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have to develop an application ASP.NET for my business. Two departments access to this application with two different urls (dept1.xxx.com, dept2.xxx.com). After authentication, i know if a user belongs to one department or the other. If the user is in the wrong url, we must redirect it to the right.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please read the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the help, and this [excellent article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very vague question, that is a process that you are going to have to define at a user level and business level.
As a starting point you can access the current URL if you wish through:

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

You can probably go from there to do something to do with determining the dept they belong to and do some logic towards the redirection if necessary.

Comment: Thanks you. With the cookie i could compare and redirect if it's necessary